# Clear All and Remove Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a script to clear all fields but won't remove all the style attributes.  How can I remove all the style attributes in the form?

Here is my code:

```
function clear_form_elements(ele) {

$(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'select-multiple':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
            $(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
 });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function clear_form_elements(ele) {
$(ele).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'select-multiple':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).removeAttr("style");
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
    }
 });

}
```

In general you can remove an attribute in a html tag using the jQuery's removeAttr("your attribute name")...here is more info about removeAttr() [JQuery's removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 2):

just add `$(elem).removeAttr("style");` where `elem` is the element/selector of the elements you want to remove the style attribute from